# "have no patient" vs "don't have patient"

Tags: conjunctions, negation, logic

Which one is correct guys?

> 1. You have no patient and courage
> 2. You don't have patient and courage

If both are correct explain me in detail please

Comment: Have you tried looking up the word "patient" Can a person "*have no patient*"? A doctor might not have *any patients* in the waiting room after a certain hour, but he or she may be a very *patient person*.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I think you mean "patience". As @shef said, "patient" is an adjective, while "patience" is the noun. There is also a noun "patient", but that refers to someone being treated by a doctor.

"You don't have patience and courage" is valid, but the "and' is unlikely. A fluent speaker would be more likely for someone to say, "You don't have patience OR courage". Using "and" means that the person doesn't have the combination. That's possible but unlikely. I could imagine someone saying, "Accomplishing this goal will require both patience and courage. And I'm sorry, but none of you have patience and courage." That would leave open the possibility that some have patience but not courage, and others have courage but not patience. But that is really stretching. More often, we'd say "you don't have patience or courage", meaning you don't have either one, or we'd say which one the person has and which he doesn't.

"You have no patience OR courage" is fine and means essentially the same thing. It is a little more emphatic because saying "you have no courage" is stronger than "you don't have courage". The first clearly says you have zero; the second is a little less forceful. The "and" here would be an even bigger problem. I just don't think a fluent speaker would say that.

Comment: "You have **neither** patience **nor** courage" is less ambiguous than the possibilities discussed in this answer.

Comment: @Jasper Fair enough, that would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct if you replace "patient" with "patience". Patient is an adjective, here you need a noun, which is "patience". The other "patient" which is a noun means a sick person. 
Otherwise both constructions "do not have" and "have no" are correct.

Comment: What about the conjunction "and"?

Comment: Normally the conjunction "or" would be used (especially in the first version), though there are probably scenarios where "and" would be OK.